# How to show category specific products like related product displayed in product detail page?

Tags: magento2

I am  trying to override related product functionality since I want to display products related based on category.

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for related product based on Category.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');

if($product){
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categories);
    $category_id = $cat->getId(); 
    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id);
    $cateinstance = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    $allcategoryproduct = $cateinstance->create()->load($category_id)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $customcollection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $customcollection->setPageSize(3);
    $customcollection->load();
}
```